# Finding all calls to a specific android sdk level

Tags: android

I need to port an Android app to an older version. That is, the app now runs in 4.0, but not in 2.2, so I need to find all API calls incompatible to 2.2 and do a workarround.

Is there any tool to do that easilly? That tool whould be theorically simple, it just had to find all function calls and check it's "@since" attribute, but I can't find one.

I wonder how other people do that. If I don't find this tool I may do it, but I don't know how much time will I have, or even if I'll have the needed skill.

Answer (score 2):

Simply change the Project Build Target to 2.2 --> Eclipse will mark everything in red, that's not supported.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the source files with which u built the APK, Right Click Project -> Properties -> Android. Select API level 8. Whatever errors you see in Java files are not supported. Simple!